# discord.py How do I let my bot send a message to different channels with different names

Tags: python, discord.py

So this is currently my code. You can see that I tried to add one more channel but it doesnt seem to work it that way.

````
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def alert(ctx, *, msg): #COMMAND NAME
    for guild in client.guilds:
        role = get(guild.roles, name = 'Wafaduck Alerts') # roles
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if(channel.name == '│wafaduck-alerts', 'wafaduck-alerts'):
                await channel.send(f"{role.mention}")```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `in` operator with a list/tuple of possible names to see if the name is one of those.

`if channel.name in ('│wafaduck-alerts', 'wafaduck-alerts')`

Comment: Wow I didnt expect it to be such a simple solution. I had a really long one, yet 'in' is the only thing missing! Thanks again for this man really appreciate it!